# Java8 streams how to replace a particular list of character with some other list of characters

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of Unicode characters that need to be replaced by some other characters I have got it working. But, I have to loop this twice to get the
result. Is it possible to loop only once and get the result?

For example, I want to replace this "\u201C","\u201D" with "\"" (smart double quote with standard double quote)
and replace "\u2018","\u2019" with "'" (smart single quote with standard single quote)

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        List<String> toRemove = Arrays.asList("\u201C","\u201D");
        List<String> toRemove1 = Arrays.asList("\u2018","\u2019");
        String text = "KURT’X45T”YUZXC";
        text=toRemove.stream()
                .map(toRem -> (Function<String,String>) s ->  s.replaceAll(toRem, "\""))
                .reduce(Function.identity(), Function::andThen)
                .apply(text);

        System.out.println("---text--- "+ text);

        text=toRemove1.stream()
            .map(toRem -> (Function<String,String>) s ->  s.replaceAll(toRem, "'"))
            .reduce(Function.identity(), Function::andThen)
            .apply(text);

        System.out.println("---text-1-- "+ text);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- This can be solved using map and then using entrySet as shown below

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
        map.put("\u2018","'");
        map.put("\u2019","'");
        map.put("\u201C","\"");
        map.put("\u201D","\"");



        List<String> toRemove = Arrays.asList("\u2018","\u2019","\u201C","\u201D");

        String text = "KURT’X45T”YUZXC";


        text=map.entrySet().stream()
                .map(e -> (Function<String,String>) s ->  s.replaceAll(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
                .reduce(Function.identity(), Function::andThen)
                .apply(text);
        System.out.println(text);

       // or you can even do like this

        text=map.entrySet().stream()
                .map(e -> (Function<String,String>) s ->  s.replaceAll(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
                .reduce(Function.identity(),(a, b) -> a.andThen(b))
                .apply(text);
        System.out.println(text);


     }
}
```